# Jackson Polymorphic deserialziation into a specific subtype failing with "InvalidTypeIdException"

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic datatype that I am trying to deserialize directly into it's subtype (for backwards compatibility), but without type info I'm not able to deserialize, even though I am directly referencing the subtype in the `readValue` call on the object mapper. Is there any Jackson magic I can use to fix this?

```
class SerializationTest {
    @Test
    fun serializationTest() {
        val serializedFoo = """ {"base":"blah", "foo": "something"} """
        val foo = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule()).readValue(serializedFoo, Foo::class.java)
        println(foo)
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    @JsonSubTypes(
            JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo::class),
            JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bar::class)
    )
    internal abstract class Base {
        abstract val base: String
    }

    internal class Foo(@JsonProperty("base") override val base: String,
                       @JsonProperty("foo") val foo: String): Base()

    internal class Bar(@JsonProperty("base") override val base: String,
                       @JsonProperty("foo") val bar: String): Base()
}
```

Fails with

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.foo.bar.SerializationTest$Foo]: missing type id property '@class'
```

I'm currently using jackson 2.9.8

Comment: Your json string `serializedFoo` is incomplete, it should have the field `"@class"` defined. Maybe you need to look into `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE` if you can't change your json string or use a custom deserializer.

Comment: I'm basically trying to get away from using a custom deserializer currently, but do that in a backwards compatible way. There's a queue that is writing/reading these so I need a way to roll out my change, ideally w/o breaking deserialization of messages already on the queue. I get why type info is needed if I were reading this into `Base` but since I'm explicitly giving it the type to deserialize to, how do I make it avoid needing the type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE`, if you can specify the concrete class in `objectmapper.readValue`.

For completeness, the javadoc from `NONE`:

> This means that no explicit type metadata is included, and typing ispurely done using contextual information possibly augmented with other annotations.

Here is a Java test case:

```
public class SerializationTest {

    @Test
    public void serializationTest() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        final String json = getSerializedFoo();
        final ObjectMapper om = getObjectMapper();

        final Foo value = om.readValue(json, Foo.class);

        assertTrue(value != null);
    }

    private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        return om;
    }

    private String getSerializedFoo() {
        return "{\"base\": \"blah\", \"foo\": \"something\"}";
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = Foo.class),
        @Type(value = Bar.class)
})
abstract class Base {

    @JsonProperty("base")
    protected String base;

    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(final String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
}

class Bar extends Base {

    @JsonProperty("bar")
    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(final String foo) {
        bar = foo;
    }
}

class Foo extends Base {

    @JsonProperty("foo")
    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(final String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```